# multicurrency enablement for CPQ

Tags: cpq, multi-currency

We have enabled multicurrency in our org.

There are some places where in Apex classes and Visualforce pages which is hard coding or returning '$'.

My concern is there is some old code and functionality which no one knows how it works or used.

For example:

```
public String getGrandTotalRequested() {

double returnVal = 0;

for (Renewal_Quote_Line_Item__c i : LineItemsList.values()) {

returnVal += i.Extended_Price_Requested__c;

}

return '$' + (returnVal.format().contains('.') ? returnVal.format() : 
(returnVal.format() + '.00'));

}
```

Above is the snippet of code which is trying to return $ and currency field.

I worried that  will it display $ USD 123 value. As after enabling multicurrency currency fields will display in USD.

Comment: What is your question about this code? You are correct that any hard-coded currency identifiers will remain hard-coded after enabling multicurrency.

Comment: @david , in old quoting tool there was a currency field, which automatically populates the "$" infront of the value. But now new cpq tool offers a currency field, which u can choose specific type of currency at the time of field creation.

Comment: So my question, is if there was a old apex code , which appends a "$" to a value, how would that behave with new cpq tool.

Comment: on new cpq tool, would it display like USD $325 ? where as in old quoting tool it used to display just $325.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the code snippet returns a string, anywhere this is displayed will simply look like

```
$325
```

I'm guessing that the code fragment you are showing is for a VF page/controller

CPQ (and for that matter, the rest of SFDC) will display for all fields of type currency:

```
USD 325.00 or
EUR 325.00 or
GBP 325.00 ...
```

You shouldn't see `USD $325` anywhere.  But you may see on some Euro quote's custom VF pages or text fields value: `$325` and elsewhere you will see `EUR 325`. Discovering all places will be the fun part.